# problem in loop mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, loops

I want to replicate my data into the database for that i have written below script,,

```
BEGIN
DECLARE a INT Default 1;

DECLARE counter INT;

SET counter=12;

WHILE counter<1010 DO
IF a=1 THEN
    insert into problem
    values(counter,'d0008','blood pressure','ajay','25-jun-1990');

    insert into med
    values(counter,'d0008','beta blocker','ajay','25-jun-1990');

    SET a=2;
END IF;

IF a=2 THEN    
    insert into problem
    values(counter,'d0009','headache','amit','25-jan-1990');

    insert into med
    values(counter,'d0009','aspirin','amit','25-jan-1990');

    SET a=3;    
END IF;

IF a=3 THEN    
    insert into problem
    values(counter,'d0011','tension','anil','25-feb-1990');

    insert into med
    values(counter,'d0011','capsule','anil','25-feb-1990');

    SET a=4;    
END IF;

IF a=4 THEN    
    insert into problem
    values(counter,'d0012','pain','ved','25-mar-1990');

    insert into med
    values(counter,'d0012','dcold','ved','25-mar-1990');

    SET a=1;    
END IF;

SET counter=counter+1;

END WHILE;
END
```

Note: first field of both the table is primary key...

I am not able to iterate this 1000 time through loop and I am getting below error

```
call abc();
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '12' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I dont know what is the problem into this procedure..

Answer (score 1):

The first `if` is executed with `counter == 12` and `a == 1`. Then you set `a = 2`, which has for effect that the second `if` runs and `counter` is still `12` so the primary key error is thrown. You're inserting two rows with the same primary key.

What you need, if I understood correctly, is to use an [`IF-ELSEIF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html) structure, and not 4 differents `IF`s.